# the + adjective + -er

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives, comparative-constructions

I'm reading an article about "object permanence" in Wikipedia. [Here is a link to the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_permanence#Recent_studies). This is the part I'm having trouble to understand:

> Evidence suggests that infants use a variety of cues while studying an
>   object and their perception of the object's permanence can be tested
>   without physically hiding the object. Rather, the object is occluded,
>   slightly obstructed, from the infants view and they are left only
>   other visual cues, such as examining the object from different
>   trajectories. It was also found that **the longer an infant focuses on
>   an object** may be due to detected discontinuities in their visual
>   field, or the flow of events, with **which** the infant has become
>   familiar.

Could you please explain a bit about the bolded part? Does it mean "detected discontinuities in the visual field of young children, or the flow of events, causes the children to spend more time looking at the object"? And, what does that "which" refer to? The flow of events, or looking at the object, or both?

Comment: Unfortunately, the sentence with the highlighted section is unpleasantly ungrammatical, probably as the result of edits that didn't rework the earlier bits after shifting the sentence around.

Comment: There are all kinds of errors present in Wikipedia articles..

Comment: Just for the record: "...I'm having trouble understanding..."

Answer (score 3):

It ***seems*** that the author originally intended to use grammatical construct "*the ... the ...*", which introduces ***proportionality*** between conditions or actions, as in

> **The more** he watched her play, **the easier** he believed...
>   **The closer** we come to the solution, **the more difficult** it appears.

See an explanation [here](http://www.englishgrammar.org/thethe-comparative-adjectives/).

In your sentence the word "*longer*" should probably be replaced with "*length of time*", making the phrase

> It was also found that **the length of time an infant focuses on an object** may be due to detected discontinuities in their visual field, or the flow of events,...

Or, it ought to be rephrased as

> It was also found that **the longer** an infant focuses on an object **the more obvious are** the discontinuities in their visual field, or the flow of events,...